# Convert hh:mm:ss to hh:mm in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have time as `04:02:00`, I want it only as `4:02` using SQL Server

I have tried this code:

```
@time time
set @time ='04:02:00' 

SELECT RIGHT(convert(varchar, @time, 100), 8)
```

It produces output:

```
4:02AM
```

please help ..

Thanks

Comment: you know what `100` in your code means?

Comment: yes it gives time into hh:ss tt format

Comment: it gives you date in us format with am/pm added, probably you need `108` instead

Comment: You can use 108 or 114 to get time in HH:MM:SS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `DATEPART` and concatenate from there:

```
SELECT 
    RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), DATEPART(HOUR, @time)), 2) + ':'  
    + RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), DATEPART(MINUTE, @time)), 2)
```

Notice the `RIGHT('00' + ..., 2)`, this is to pad the `hour` or `minute` part with leading zeroes so that it'll be two characters long, e.g `4` becomes `04`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use:

```
DECLARE @dt DATETIME
    SET @dt = GETDATE()
    SELECT CONVERT(varchar(5),@dt,108)
```

This query gives result in the format 'HH:mm'.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes you are right. You can use 108 or 114 to get time in HH:MM:SS

Answer (score 3):

DECLARE @time datetime
set @time ='04:02:00'

SELECT LEFT(RIGHT(convert(varchar, @time, 100), 8), 6)

Comment: use left to select specific value.Though @Artyom Pranovich answer is good one